# Extend Interface if the interface is in an external DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface

I work with a asp.net MVC application and in that application there is in a interface

But that interface is in a 3rd party DLL. So I can't modify the interface.

```
#region Assembly Sana.Commerce, Version=9.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2b26dc7ce8e04e9f
// D:\visualstudio2015\Sana Training\SDK\SDK\Libraries\Sana.Commerce.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sana.Commerce.Customer;
using Sana.Commerce.Shop;

namespace Sana.Commerce.Order
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     This interface represents an order in the ERP system. This can be an order that
    //     still has to be placed or an order that is already in the ERP (for example order
    //     history). There are several types of orders like regular orders, invoice and
    //     quotes. The type of order is stored in the document type property.
    public interface IOrder : IEntity, IVersionedItem
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     ID of the account that placed the order.
        string AccountId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The type of account that placed this order.
        AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the list of order attachments.
        IList<IAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the status of order authorization.
        OrderAuthorizationStatus AuthorizationStatus { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Address that will recieve the invoice.
        ICustomerAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets bill-to name.
        string BillToName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the comment.
        string Comment { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the Contact that placed this order.
        string Contact { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     ID of the Contact that placed this order.
        string ContactId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But in the `IOrder` I have to put an extra properties `ProjectNumber`.

But how to extend the `IOrder` interface if it is in another DLL?

I try it like this:

```
public  interface IOrderProjectNumber:IOrder
{
    string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

}
```

But then I have a method, like this:

```
public override IOrder SaveOrder(IOrder order)
{

    IOrderProjectNumber orderNumber= new OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber();
    orderNumber.ProjectNumber = "hallo";     

    return base.SaveOrder(order);
}
```

So I change the method with this:

```
public override IOrder SaveOrder(IOrderProjectNumber order)
{

    IOrderProjectNumber orderNumber= new OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber();
    orderNumber.ProjectNumber = "hallo";     

    return base.SaveOrder(order);
}
```

But then I get the error:

> Code  Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>   CS0115    'ExtendedOrderManager.SaveOrder(IOrderProjectNumber)': no
>   suitable method found to
>   override  Sana.Commerce.Sdk   D:\visualstudio2015\Sana
>   Training\SDK\SDK\Sana.Commerce.Sdk\Customization\Order\ExtendedOrderManager.cs    19  32  Active

it will be saved like xml:

```
<Order>
  <field name="BlanketOrderId" type="System.String, mscorlib" storeWithEntity="True">
    <string>BO1</string>
  </field>
  <field name="CustomField" type="System.String, mscorlib" storeWithEntity="False">
    <string>myvalue</string>
  </field>
  <field name="PaymentStatus" type="System.String, mscorlib">
    <string>new</string>
  </field>
  <field name="ProjectNumber" type="Null" />
  <field name="BillingAddress" type="Sana.Commerce.Customer.CustomerAddress, Sana.Commerce.Sdk">
    <CustomerAddress>
      <field name="CustomerId" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>01454545</string>
      </field>
      <field name="Address" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>705 West Peachtree Street</string>
      </field>
      <field name="Address2" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string />
      </field>
      <field name="ZipCode" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>US-GA 31772</string>
      </field>
      <field name="City" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>Atlanta</string>
      </field>
      <field name="CountryId" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>US</string>
      </field>
      <field name="CountryName" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>Verenigde Staten</string>
      </field>
      <field name="State" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string />
      </field>
      <field name="PhoneNo" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string />
      </field>
      <field name="FaxNo" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string />
      </field>
      <field name="Contact" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>Ms. Tammy L. McDonald</string>
      </field>
      <field name="ContactId" type="Null" />
      <field name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib">
        <string>New Concepts Furniture</string>
      </field>
      <field name="Id" type="Null" />
      <field name="WebsiteId" type="Null" />
    </CustomerAddress>
  </field>
```

and in the Order class. I put the extra propertie:

```
public class Order : Entity, IOrder
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Status of the Payment of this order.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }



        [DataMember]
        [XmlField]
        public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The system works with Dependency injection and where you register your models and controllers. Registering new classes will be done in the Addone class, like this:

```
public class Addon : IAddon
    {
        public int Order
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            ObjectManager.RegisterType<IController, ReturnOrdersController>("ReturnOrders");
            ObjectManager.RegisterType<OrderOverviewModel, OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber>();
        }
    }
```

and this is the OrderoverViewModel:

```
//
    // Summary:
    //     The order overview page model.
    public class OrderOverviewModel : CheckoutBaseViewModel
    {
        public OrderOverviewModel();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating that the terms and conditions is confirmed.
        [MustBeTrue(ErrorMessageResourceName = "OrderOverview_AgreeTermsError")]
        public virtual System.Boolean AcceptTerms { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the comments.
        [AllowHtml]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Name = "Comments")]
        [MaxLength(2048, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLength")]
        public virtual System.String Comments { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the delivery date.
        [Display(Name = "RequestedDeliveryDate")]
        [GreaterThanToday(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_InvalidField")]
        public virtual Date? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating that the order will be paid online.
        public virtual System.Boolean IsPaidOnline { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the reference number.
        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "ReferenceNumber")]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLength")]
        public virtual System.String ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether additional information will be visible.
        public virtual System.Boolean ShowAdditionalInformation { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Applies the model changes to the specified basket.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   basket:
        //     The basket to update.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     Returns a value indicating whether any changes have been done to the basket.
        public virtual System.Boolean ApplyChanges(IBasket basket);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes the model using the specified basket.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   basket:
        //     The basket.
        public virtual void Initialize(IBasket basket);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes the model.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   context:
        //     The shop context.
        //
        //   generalInfo:
        //     The checkout general info model.
        public virtual void InitializeGeneral(ShopContext context, CheckoutGeneralInfo generalInfo);
    }
```

This is still null:

```
public  interface IOrderProjectNumber : IOrder
    {
        string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
        //public virtual IOrder SaveOrder(IOrder order);

    }

 var orderObject = order as DomainModel.Order.IOrderProjectNumber;
```

orderObject is still null. I dont understand that.

Comment: Do you have to use the given IOrder interface? You could instead subclas it and declare your required members in your subclassed interface.

Comment: Thank you. I update the post

Comment: You can't override with a different type parameter. You must still take in `IOrder`. You can go "hunting" for that other interface in your overridden method, by checking if it implements the interface, but unfortunately you cannot *require* the parameter to be your new interface type. In short, you can't really get what you want with full type safety.

Comment: As a side-note, why are you using an interface at all for this? Why not just do `var orderNumber = new OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber(); orderNumber.ProjectNumber = "hallo";`? This should allow you to set the property on the object without going through an interface. This object would have to implement `IOrder` and thus be compatible with `base.SaveOrder`. However, what then is the purpose of the parameter into the method since you're constructing a new object inside? In short, it is quite difficult to give you good advice when we don't really know why you're doing the things you do.

Comment: Go back to the first version,  `SaveOrder(IOrder order)`. But look at the content, there is no connection or exchange between orderNumber and order.

Comment: I have seen you updated your code and provided implementation for the Order class, so i updated my Code presenting a possible solution. Now you don't need an additional interface, you can just check if you class is an Ordre instance. For my previous solution the Ordre class also hat to implement the IOrderProjectNumber interface, what it did not, that's why you got a null object trying to cast inside the SaveOrder method.

Answer (score 0):

Your SaveOrder method should look like:

```
public override IOrder SaveOrder(IOrder order)
{    
    var orderObject = order as Order;

    if(orderObject != null)
    {
        orderObject.ProjectNumber = "hallo";     
    }

    return base.SaveOrder(order);
}
```

Comment: THank you for your comment. But orderNumber  is now null

Comment: Is still null I mean

Comment: If the underlying object does not implement `IOrderProjectNumber`, then yes, that will be `null`.

Comment: Who is the caller of the SaveOrder method, do you initiate the call or does it originate in the 3-rd part component? You should also clear the question, where the input parameter (order) is instantiated.You then must change (m.b. override) the instantiatin method and return and instance implementing your inherited interfaces. When this part is done, the input parameter of the SaveMethod will implement also the IOrderProjectNumber interface and everythig will be fine. It's a little bit difficult to give you a valid answer without knowing the applications architecture.

Comment: I think you meant: `order as IOrderProjectNumber`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman at that moment i have not seen the implementation of the `Order` class, and it does not implement `IOrderProjectNumber` so `order as IOrderProjectNumber` will always return null. If `Order` class would implement `IOrderProjectNumber` interface than my previous proposal would stay correct and would be absolutely the prefered way.

Comment: But projectNumber is still  null

Comment: I don't see why you would need to know about  the Order or OrderProjectNumber classes. As long as something implements it, and we know the interfaces are related.

Comment: You are absolutely right, unfortunally does `Order` class not implement the desired `IOrderProjectNumber ` interface.

Comment: @HoicodeEngineerKing do you have any documentation about how the original SaveOrder method does work and which elements it does persist? Possibly it persists only elements, contained by the `IOrder` interface, in this case you are out of luck and you have to investigate about low level persistence methods and call them for your `ProjectNumber` property.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Can I sent you email?

Comment: Have somebody any ideer? Thank you

Comment: Somebody there? Hello?